# Get value of dropdownbox 1 and use dropdownbox2's value as a cell indicator where to paste it

Tags: excel, vba, dropdownbox

I have 2 drop down boxes and a button. Drop box 1 has numbers from 1 to 30, and Drop box 2 has numbers from 1 to 130.

What I need is a way to take the value of Drop box 2 and - having Drop box 1's value as a row number - paste it into the C column of another sheet, allowing for live data editing.

Note: I am a complete noob to VB. The Drop down boxes and button are on the chart sheet if that makes it any different. Also I have to have the drop boxes on the chart sheet, not the data sheet.

I have tried selecting drop box values however am unable to figure out the correct way to do so. Things such as `DropBox2.Value` & `DropBox2.Value.Select` don't seem to work (most likely doing it wrong). Googled various ways of how to get drop box value and paste elsewhere but to no avail. Apologies for wasting anyone's time if this seems mundane.

```
Sub TEST()
    ' TEST Macro
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    DropBox2.Value.Select
    ActiveSheet.Cell("$C""DropBox1.Value").Select
    Selection.Paste
    Chart2.Select
End Sub
```

Expected to do what I said in the description however the error message

> Object required

appears.

Comment: What kind of drop down boxes are you using? Are you using the ComboBox form control? Or maybe the ActiveX control ComboBox?

Comment: @StavrosJon I am using the ComboBox from Controls in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim varDrowDown1 As Variant: varDrowDown1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value
    Dim varDrowDown2 As Variant: varDrowDown2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 2").OLEFormat.Object.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(varDrowDown1, 1).Value = varDrowDown2
End Sub
```

Check that the names of the objects are correct. I assumed Sheet1 is where the Drop Down Boxes are, Drop Down 1 and Drop Down 2 are their names, Sheet2 is the Worksheet where you want to copy the Value to, and you would like to insert it into the first column.

You can find the name of your Drop Down Boxes by right clicking them and looking at the place where the Active Cell's reference (e.g. A1) usually appears. The Sheets' Name is trivial, and you should know the column's number, too.

Comment: Okay so I have Sheet 1 and Chart 2 that i'm using. The Drop down boxes (Which I believe are ComboBoxes from Controls) are located on the chart itself, along with the button. 

I tried the code, changing the sheets and boxes to the correct names however it says "The item with the specified name wasn't found." Hope this helps!

Comment: On which line do you get this error? I suppose, the first one. Could you please post a picture of the chart after right clicking on one of the ComboBoxes?

Comment: Yeah it's the first line, after 'Dim varDrowDown1 As Variant". Unfortunately I can't screengrab on my work PC :(

Comment: Then try to determine the object's exact name by using the Watch window (insert ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") and see if it displays it or you get an error, if it works, insert ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1") and see if it works or not, etc.)

Comment: It's been sorted:

Sheets("Chart2").Select
 Dim varDropDown1 As Variant: varDropDown1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart2").Shapes("DropDown1").OLEFormat.Object.Value
    Dim varDropDown2 As Variant: varDropDown2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart2").Shapes("DropDown2").OLEFormat.Object.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(varDropDown1, 3).Value = varDropDown2

That's the code, in case anyone else has the same problem

Comment: Are you sure you need the first line with Select? Did you try if it works without it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Chart2").Select
 Dim varDropDown1 As Variant: varDropDown1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart2").Shapes("DropDown1").OLEFormat.Object.Value
    Dim varDropDown2 As Variant: varDropDown2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart2").Shapes("DropDown2").OLEFormat.Object.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(varDropDown1, 3).Value = varDropDown2
```

Sorted, thank you for all of your help!